# how to rout the request when every page is going from index page in php

Tags: php

my project every page is going through index page through htaccess...so how to redirect each page..here is my index.php page which include first page..but when i request another page..it not redirect to that page...only blank page is displayed..

```
require ('class/class.database.php');
require ('config.php');

$requestURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$requestURI = str_replace(SUBDIR,'',$requestURI);
$requestParse = explode('/',$requestURI);

$page = array_shift($requestParse);
print_r($requestParse);
if($page == "")
{
    $page = DEFAULT_PAGE;
}
include 'views/'.$page.'.php';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hv solved it..now it redirect to page after index page
    $requestURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $requestURI = str_replace(SUBDIR,'',$requestURI);
        $temp = explode('?',$requestURI);
        $requestURI = array_shift($temp);
        $requestParse = explode('/',$requestURI);
        $page = array_shift($requestParse);
        $action = array_shift($requestParse);

```
    if($action == '')
    {   
        $action = DEFAULT_ACTION_PAGE;
    }


    $includeFile = 'views/'.$page.'/'.$action.'.php';

    if(file_exists($includeFile))
    {
        require $includeFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for debugging:

1. echo $page just before your include to ensure it is what you expect it to be.  Your code echoes a previous variable which is not the one you end up using.
2. create a views/$page.php file that does something simple like echo('yay');
3. Call your simple page and see if it does what you expect.